# reduceByKey doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a RDD that looks like this :

```
[...('marseilles_2', 'SEP', '23'),
 ('marseilles_2', 'OCT', '28'),
 ('marseilles_2', 'NOV', '24'),
 ('marseilles_2', 'DEC', '26'),
 ('nantes', 'JAN', '16'),
 ('nantes', 'FEB', '15'),
 ('nantes', 'MAR', '20'),
 ('nantes', 'APR', '12'),
 ('nantes', 'MAY', '21'),
 ('nantes', 'JUN', '28'),
 ('nantes', 'JUL', '19'),
 ('nantes', 'AUG', '11'),
 ('nantes', 'SEP', '13'),
 ('nantes', 'OCT', '14'),
 ('nantes', 'NOV', '14'),
 ('nantes', 'DEC', '24'),
 ('nice', 'JAN', '16'),
 ('nice', 'FEB', '15'),
 ('nice', 'MAR', '20')...]
```

I need to compute the mean of the third column. So I created another RDD with the first column as key and the third as value like so:

```
cityAndRevenue = filesRDD.map(lambda kv: (kv[0], kv[2]))
```

And then I tried to group the RDD by key by doing so:

```
from operator import add
cityAndRevenue.reduceByKey(add)
```

But when I collect it, it didn't work.. it's like I never called `reduceByKey()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have strings in the third column, could that be the problem?

Comment: Indeed, corrected it but still doesn't work!

Comment: Have you assigned the result to some variable? `resultrdd = cityAndRevenue.reduceByKey(add)` and then check `resultrdd`? You should not expect `reduceByKey` to modify your `rdd` it returns a new rdd.

Comment: ahah jeez this is it.. I'm dumb. Thanks mate!